# Adding Subitems with the Data Exchange Framework

Tags: data-exchange-framework

I am currently working on a Proof of Concept using the Data Exchange. I have implemented the demo from the [Sitecore Documentation](http://integrationsdn.sitecore.net/DataExchangeFramework/v1.1/getting-started/index.html).

The example is working as expected. However, I need to create subitems based on a Branch Template but I don't know how since I just started working on the Data Exchange Framework.

So, in brief, I have a Container in the Sitecore Content Tree. Under the Container, the Data Exchange will create the items. Right now, all items are being created under the container. I need to have the item structure as below:

[image]

Can anyone provide a sample code or link to achieve this. I am new to Data Exchange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After lot of investigation, I have seen that the Branch Template cannot be used since I get the following error:

`Template is invalid (cdbb9572-14b6-4ea2-818e-bb6c15beda94)`

The reason is because of the Add Method from the namespace

`Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.Data.ItemRepository`

Below is the Code for creating the item:

```cs
public Guid Add(ItemCreateRequest request, string databaseName, string language)
{
  Database database = ItemRepository.GetDatabase(databaseName);
  Language language1 = ItemDataBase.GetLanguage(language);
  Item obj = database.GetItem(request.ParentPath, language1);
  if (obj == null)
    throw new ArgumentException(ItemDataBase.InvalidParameterMessage("Path", (object) request.ParentPath));
  TemplateItem template = database.GetTemplate(new ID(request.Template));
  if (template == null)
    throw new ArgumentException(ItemDataBase.InvalidParameterMessage("Template", (object) request.Template));
  Item itemToUpdate = obj.Add(request.Name, template);
  using (new EditContext(itemToUpdate))
    this.UpdateFields(request.Fields, itemToUpdate);
  return itemToUpdate.ID.Guid;
}
```

The above code is used for creating an item from a template and not from a Branch Template. For Branch Template it should have been as below:

```cs
private const string _BRANCH_ITEM = "/sitecore/templates/Branches/MyBranches/MyBranch";

public void Create(Item parent, string name)
{
   BranchItem branch = globalDataFolder.Database.GetItem(_BRANCH_ITEM);
   Assert.IsNotNull(branch, "Could not find Data branch at " + _BRANCH_ITEM);
   parent.Add(name, branch);
}
```

The difference is instead of using `TemplateItem`, it need to be changed to `BranchItem` in order to create item from Branch Template. Example is taken from Brian Pedersen [post](https://www.google.mu/amp/s/briancaos.wordpress.com/2009/12/01/creating-items-from-branches-in-sitecore/amp/?client=safari)

It seems that the only way to achieve this is to override the ItemRepository and implement a new method that caters for Branch Template. Maybe, introducing the creation of items from Branch Template in future releases of the Sitecore Data Exchange Framework might be considered.

Comment: hello i am looking for this solution.The answer "override the ItemRepository and implement a new method that caters for Branch Template" makes sense.Can you let m eknow how to override the itemrepository and where to configure? Where should i add the code.can you eloborate solution.

Comment: It's been a while since I have not check this code. You may need to search for the pipeline ItemRepository and add in your custom code.

Comment: Preferably ask a new question