# Sitecore Data Exchange Framework Branch Template Issue Template is invalid

Tags: templates, data-exchange-framework, branch

I am working on importing the data from file system provider into Sitecore using Data Exchange framework.While adding the content using regular template in sitecore, the items are imported fine.But I wanted to use Branch template to create the item in the sitecore.I can not create item based on branch template because while debugging the code I have encountered in to source code provided in the [Adding Subitems with the Data Exchange Framework](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1956/adding-subitems-with-the-data-exchange-framework) answer and according to which, it checks only for template item and not branch item.

The suggested answer in the above thread which says to "override the ItemRepository and implement a new method that caters for Branch Template" but it does not explain how to do it.

I have tried so far,
Overriding the item creation using all `HttpBegin` request pipelines and all item events like item:creating,Item:saving and Item:adding but no solution seem to overwrite the `Itemrepository` method.

Also, The Add method in `Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.Data.ItemRepository` can not be overwritten from anywhere in pipelines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Override **InProcItemModelRepository** class.
2. Create patch file to override item model repository.

Have look at ***Sitecore.DataExchange.Local.config***

There is configuration to specify item model repository.

```
<dataExchange>
        <tenantRepository type="Sitecore.DataExchange.Repositories.Tenants.SitecoreTenantRepository, Sitecore.DataExchange">
            <itemModelRepository ref="dataExchange/itemModelRepository" />
        </tenantRepository>
        <itemModelRepository type="Sitecore.DataExchange.Local.Repositories.InProcItemModelRepository, Sitecore.DataExchange.Local">
            <databaseName>master</databaseName>
        </itemModelRepository>
        <logger type="Sitecore.DataExchange.Local.Loggers.PrefixedSitecoreLogger, Sitecore.DataExchange.Local">
            <prefix>Data Exchange</prefix>
        </logger>
        <pipelineBatchLoggerService type="Sitecore.DataExchange.Local.Loggers.PipelineBatchLoggerService, Sitecore.DataExchange.Local" />
    </dataExchange>
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see an `Add` method in the `InProcItemModelRepository` when overriding the class mentioned above (overriding `Add` is mentioned in the linked question). I overrode the `CreateItem` method to have the default code with a few checks marked with comments as custom code as follows:

```
namespace Common.CustomSitecore.DataExchange.Repositories
{
    public class CustomInProcItemModelRepository : Sitecore.DataExchange.Local.Repositories.InProcItemModelRepository
    {
        protected override Guid CreateItem(ItemModel itemModel)
        {
            if (itemModel == null || !itemModel.ContainsKey("ParentID"))
                return Guid.Empty;
            var result1 = Guid.Empty;
            var obj1 = itemModel["ParentID"];
            if (!Guid.TryParse(obj1?.ToString(), out result1) || result1 == Guid.Empty)
                return Guid.Empty;
            var obj2 = itemModel["TemplateID"];
            Guid result2;
            if (!Guid.TryParse(obj2?.ToString(), out result2) || result2 == Guid.Empty)
                return Guid.Empty;
            itemModel["TemplateID"] = (object)result2.ToString();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)itemModel["ItemName"]))
                return Guid.Empty;
            var itemModel1 = Get(result1, (string)null, 0);
            if (itemModel1 == null)
                return Guid.Empty;
            string empty = string.Empty;
            if (itemModel.ContainsKey("ItemLanguage") && itemModel["ItemLanguage"] != null)
                empty = itemModel["ItemLanguage"].ToString();
            itemModel.Remove("ParentID");
            itemModel.Remove("ItemLanguage");

            var createdItemModel = this.CreateItemModelWithStringFieldValues(itemModel);

            //custom check to get the template to add's template. We will later check if 
            //this is a normal template or a branch template
            Guid templateOrBranchId;
            ItemModel templateOrBranch = null;
            if (Guid.TryParse(createdItemModel?["TemplateID"]?.ToString(), out templateOrBranchId))
            {
                templateOrBranch = Get(templateOrBranchId);
            }


            //if a branch template add via the branch template add and update otherwise do the default
            Guid responseId = Guid.Empty;
            if (createdItemModel != null && templateOrBranch?["TemplateID"]?.ToString() == Sitecore.TemplateIDs.BranchTemplate.Guid.ToString())
            {
                var db = Factory.GetDatabase(DatabaseName);

                Language branchLanguage;
                var validLanguage = Language.TryParse(empty, out branchLanguage);

                var branch = validLanguage ? db.GetItem(new ID(templateOrBranchId), branchLanguage) 
                    : db.GetItem(new ID(templateOrBranchId));

                var parent = validLanguage ? db.GetItem(itemModel1["ItemPath"].ToString(), branchLanguage) 
                    : db.GetItem(itemModel1["ItemPath"].ToString());

                var newItem = parent.Add(createdItemModel["ItemName"].ToString(), (BranchItem)branch);

                if (newItem == null)
                {
                    Log.Error("Could not create item", this);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Assuming branch's main item is $name, otherwise use the first that can be found
                    var mainItem = branch.Children["$name"] ?? branch.Children.FirstOrDefault();
                    if (mainItem == null)
                    {
                        Context.Logger.Error($"Could not find a main template in a branch item: {branch.ID}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        createdItemModel[ItemModel.TemplateID] = mainItem.TemplateID;
                        Update(newItem.ID.Guid, createdItemModel, newItem.Language.Name, newItem.Version.Number);
                    }

                    responseId = newItem.ID.Guid;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //this part is not custom. It is the default functionality that adds from a template
                responseId = (this.HandlerProvider.GetHandler<CreateItemHandler>().Handle(
                    (HandlerRequest) new CreateItemCommand()
                    {
                        Database = this.DatabaseName,
                        ItemModel = createdItemModel,
                        Path = itemModel1["ItemPath"].ToString(),
                        Language = empty
                    }) as CreateItemResponse).ItemId;
            }

            return responseId;
        }
    }
}
```

I potentially could have tried to override the default config entry for my instance shown in the following config snippet. **Don't** make this config change if you are using the code from above (`CustomInProcItemModelRepository`) as it is not directly related. If using `CustomInProcItemModelRepository` patch the config mentioned in Vlad's post:

```
<itemRepository type="Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Data.SitecoreData.ItemRepository, Sitecore.PathAnalyzer" singleInstance="true">
   <param ref="pathAnalyzer/configuration" desc="configuration"/>
</itemRepository>
```