# Don't Index An Item In DEF Until All Items Have Been Added

Tags: indexing, data-exchange-framework

I'm creating a large number of items using Data Exchange Framework (DEF). It looks like the items are being indexed one at a time when created/updated. I have a pipeline step that indexes a subtree of items and would like to stop other pipeline steps from indexing items created by the `Resolve Multilanguage Sitecore Item Dictionary Pipeline Step` and edited by the `Update Sitecore Item Pipeline Step`. I can't just wrap the `InProcItemModelRepository` `Create` and `Update` methods with an event disabler because some of them use branch templates and disabling events causes issues when adding from a branch ([code doing so can be seen here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/10889/1436)). I don't want to disable indexing site wide if possible, only for this group of items being added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a custom pipeline processor that can be used as the `Processor Type` for a `Iterate Data and Run Pipelines Pipeline Step` item. All it really does is wrap the method that runs pipeline steps in the linked pipelines in a `BulkUpdateContext` which seems to be good enough. I made this change on the standard values of the `Iterate Data and Run Pipelines Pipeline Step` which is not something everyone should do unless they plan on just using that step to map to Sitecore items which works for my use case. `BulkUpdateContext.IsActive` was true while debugging through the pipeline steps that created/update items so it looks like this should work for me.

```
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Attributes;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Contexts;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Models;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Plugins;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Common.CustomSitecore.DataExchange.Processors.PipelineSteps
{
    [RequiredPipelineStepPlugins(new[] { typeof(PipelinesSettings), typeof(DataLocationSettings) })]
    [RequiredPipelineContextPlugins(new[] { typeof(IterableDataSettings) })]
    public class IterateAndRunPipelinesStepProcessor : Sitecore.DataExchange.Processors.PipelineSteps.IterateAndRunPipelinesStepProcessor
    {
        protected override void ProcessPipelines(PipelineStep pipelineStep, ICollection<Pipeline> subPipelines,
            PipelineContext pipelineContext)
        {
            using (new BulkUpdateContext())
            {
                base.ProcessPipelines(pipelineStep, subPipelines, pipelineContext);
            }
        }
    }
}
```